# Thread-safe Factory pattern without control over Derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring

Say I have a class `'Car'` with a complicated tree of subclasess. Each class has a unique id. I have a management class that keeps track of pointers to all cars and can look them up based on the `id`.

```
class Car {
public:
    using CarId = size_t;
    Car* getCar(CarId id) const { return sMap[id]; }
    Car(){
        sMutex.lock();
        mId = ++sLastId;
        sMap.insert(pair(mId,this));
        sMutex.unlock();
    }
private:
    static map<CarId,Car*> sMap;
    static CarId sLastId;
    static mutex sMutex;
    CarId mId;
}
```

I want to refactor this so that the `Car::getCar` returns `weak_ptr<Car>` as returning raw pointers causes a hell lot of problems.

However, to add weak pointer to itself into `sMap` from a constructor in a naive way one needs to create a shared pointer, which immediately destroys the object as it gets out of scope:

```
sMutex.lock();
mId = ++sLastId;
sMap.insert(
    pair(mId,
         weak_ptr<Car>(shared_ptr(this))
    )
);
sMutex.unlock();
```

Shit, I guess I'll need to use some factory:

```
class CarFactory {
public:
    shared_ptr<Car> createCar(){
        sMutex.lock();
        mId = ++sLastId;
        auto res = shared_ptr<Car>(this);
        sMap.insert(
            pair(mId,
                 weak_ptr<Car>(res)
            )
        );
        sMutex.unlock();
        return result;
    }

private:
    map<CarId,Car*> sMap;
    CarId sLastId;
    mutex sMutex;
}
```

Nice, but there is a lot of derived classes, many times in modules that I can not include from here, so I can not have a factory method for every possible Car derived type defined here, it would be quite impractical. However I need every car to be tracked, I can not allow any way to create derived cars that does not go through the factory method.

The best solution I have come up with so far:

```
class CarFactory {
...
template<class DT, class Tp>
shared_ptr<DT> create(Tp params...)
{
    sMutex.lock();
    mId = ++sLastId;
    auto res = shared_ptr<Car>(new DT(forward(params)...) );
    sMap.insert(
        pair(mId,
             weak_ptr<Car>(res)
        )
    );
    sMutex.unlock();
    return result;
}
...
}
```

Which allows to privatize derived classes constructor:

```
class VolksWagenGolf : public VolksWagen {
    friend class CarFactory;
private:
    VolksWagen(bool enableEmissionCheat);
}
```

Hence I can create it only as follows:

```
shared_ptr<Car> myCar = CarFactory::create<VolksWagenGolf>(true);
```

Right, but I still don't like it because:

1. It is a template, for various reasons it would be better to do it without a template.
2. Any time a colleague unaware of this mechanism can come and declare a new Car type with a public constructor as he was used to do always. But now when he uses that public constructor, his cars are not going to be tracked.

So if you have any ideas how to implement such a pattern where every derived class has to be created through the centralized bookkeeping mechanism while using weak pointers at the same time for tracking, please let me know.

Comment: Making `Car`s constructor private and `CarFactory::create` a `friend` could solve problem 2.

Comment: But if I make Car's constructor private, then I can not inherit from it at all, can I?

Comment: You're right. That was a brain fart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: create a protected car constructor.  It requires a token that is owned by your factory function: only the factory function has permission to create that token.

Now no code that tries to create a derived car can, without that token.

```
class CarFactory {
private:
  struct CarConstructionPermission {
    explicit CarConstructionPermission(int) {};
  };
  friend class Car;
public:
  template<class D, class...Args>
  std::shared_ptr<D> create(Args&&...args) {
    // blah blah
    auto retval = std::make_shared<D>( CarConstructionPermission(0), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    // blah
    return retval;
  }
};
class Car {
protected:
  explicit Car(CarConstructionPermission) {}
};
```

Step 2: Make the template body partly hidden.

What you need is a function from () to shared_ptr.

```
private:
  bool create_internal(std::function< std::shared_ptr<Car>() > producer);

public:
  template<class D, class...Args>
  std::shared_ptr<D> create(Args&&...args) {
    std::shared_ptr<D> retval;
    if (create_internal([&]{
      retval = std::make_shared<D>( CarConstructionPermission(0), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
      return retval;
    }) {
      return retval;
    }
    return {}; // failure
  }
```

now all the mutex stuff is inside `create_internal`; we type erase creating the car and pass that in.

`create_internal` now looks much like your `create`, but isn't a template, returns `bool`, and takes 1 parameter.  `auto result = producer();` replaces the `shared_ptr<Car>` line.

Comment: Magnificent! The only issue I see here is that if I want to create a derived class `class Ford : public Car`, I need to declare a constructor `Ford(CarConstructionPermission)`. But can I do that if the permission is private within the Factory? Anyway I guess that even if it does not work as is I can fix it by making the Permission public and only it's constructor private (with Factory as a friend of Permission). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jlan ya, I mussed that.  Private ctor, type is public, car is friend is solution.